# Special characters in a string [JAVA]

Tags: java

folks, the method below would throw an Exception if other character than `"01xX \t"`(including whitespace and \t inside a passed String) is found. If I have this String `"1 x \tX 00"`, the method should return `[1,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,0,0]` but Im getting only `[1,X,X,0,0]` in which the `'whitespace'` and `'\t'` somehow are not getting included. `'Whitespace'` and `'\n'` also should return `'X'`. Please could smb help me?

```
    //Here's the test case that I'm failing
     @Test (timeout=3000) public void signal13(){
        String inp = "1 x \tX 00";
        List<Signal> expecteds = Signal.fromString(inp);
        assertEquals(expecteds, Arrays.asList(new Signal[]{Signal.HI, Signal.X, Signal.X, Signal.LO, Signal.LO}));
      }





    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


public enum Signal {

    HI, LO, X;


    public Signal invert()
    {
        if(this == HI)
            return LO;
        else if(this == LO)
            return HI;
        else if(this == X)
            return X;

        return this;
    }

    public static Signal fromString(char c)
    {

        if(c == '1')
            return HI;
        else if(c == '0')
            return LO;
        else if(c == 'X')
            return X;
        else if(c == 'x')
            return X;
        else
            throw new ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal(c, "Invalid character!");

    }

    public static List <Signal> fromString(String inps)
    {
        List<Signal> values = new ArrayList<Signal>();
        for(int i = 0; i < inps.length(); i++)
        {
            if(inps.charAt(i) == '1')
                values.add(HI);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == '0')
                values.add(LO);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == 'X')
                values.add(X);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == 'x')
                values.add(X);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == ' ')
                values.add(X);
            else if(inps.charAt(i) == '\t')
            {
                values.add(X);
                values.add(X);
            }
            else 
                throw new ExceptionLogicMalformedSignal(inps.charAt(0), "Invalid character!");
        }
        return values;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        if(this == HI)
            return "1";
        else if(this == LO)
            return "0";
        else if(this == X)
            return "X";

        return "Error here!";
    }
    public static String toString(List<Signal> sig)
    {
        String result = "";
        ArrayList<Signal> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Signal x: sig)
        {
            temp.add(x);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
        {
            if(temp.get(i) == HI)
                result += "1";
            else if(temp.get(i) == LO)
                result += "0";
            else if(temp.get(i) == X)
                result += "X";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've provided does not reproduce the behavior you've observed. http://ideone.com/CZM804 Please provide a [minimal but *complete* example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the problem.

Comment: I assume it should be enough what the method does. Or not? @Radiodef

Comment: @Yuri This code does not behave as you described. Either you described it wrong or you aren't running this code.

Comment: Folks, I'm testing my professor's test cases with JUnit. But does the logic of the code look fine? @EJP

Comment: As per my earlier comment, *the method you've shown us works*. The error is elsewhere or the code you've shown us is different.

Comment: @Yuri I run your code with the input you provided and it work fine.... share the complete code so we will find the error that you see

Comment: Alright, I updated the code and added the test case as well! @Mzf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like the assertion is not correct, it's:

```
 assertEquals(expecteds, Arrays.asList(new Signal[]{Signal.HI, Signal.X, Signal.X, Signal.LO, Signal.LO}));
```

while it should be :

```
List<Signal> actual = Signal.fromString(inp);
List<Signal> expected = Arrays.asList(new Signal[]{Signal.HI, Signal.X, Signal.X,Signal.X,Signal.X,Signal.X,Signal.X,Signal.X, Signal.LO, Signal.LO});
 assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

Because the expected result is `[1,X,X,X,X,X,X,X,0,0]`

Comment: It’s good that you renamed the variable from `expected` to `actual` to represent it’s real role but you should also swap the parameters of `assertEquals` as (assuming it’s JUnit) the first parameter represents the expected value and the second the actual. Otherwise, the resulting exception’s message will be as confusing as demonstrated by this question. As a side note, `Arrays.asList` doesn’t require manual array creation. `Arrays.asList(Signal.HI, Signal.X, …)` will do as well.

Answer (score 0):

here is a modified version of your code that works as you need it...

```
private String fromString(String inps) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < inps.length(); i++) {
        if (inps.charAt(i) == '1') {
            sb.append("1");
        } else if (inps.charAt(i) == '0') {
            sb.append("0");
        } else if (inps.charAt(i) == 'X') {
            sb.append("x");
        } else if (inps.charAt(i) == 'x') {
            sb.append("x");
        } else if (inps.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            sb.append("x");
        } else if (inps.charAt(i) == '\t') {
            sb.append("x");
            sb.append("x");
        } else {
            throw new Exception("invalid character");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

When you output `fromString("1 x \tX 00")` you get the result `1xxxxxxx00` as expected.

Hope this helps